# ssh - execute a gtk python app over remote ssh?

Tags: python, ssh

I'm writing a gtk python app that I'm testing on an ubuntu laptop, however I'm writing the script on my win7 desktop (sftp to update the script the laptop).

If I try to execute the script via SSH such as:

```
python /path/to/app.py
```

It gives me errors since obviously gtk won't render a window in putty such as:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
```

My question is, is there a way to execute the script via remote ssh that will open fine on the laptop? Its kind of a pain to have to save the script, then lean over and execute the script on the laptop.

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: So your script is stored in the Ubuntu laptop and you are editing it on your Windows desktop. You want that the window appears on your Windows system or in the Ubuntu one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install a X server on your Windows 7: http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/

Then, don't forget to do `ssh -X` when you start the remote script.